# ERROR: Plugin 'ADBMobile_PhoneGap' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml in Phonegap 2.5 IOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, adobe-analytics

I am using cordova 2.5 for phone gap IOS app developement. When adding Adobe Marketing Cloud plugin, Xcode IDE log shows this error.

I have followed the integration steps as per the following link.
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/mobile/ios/phonegap.html
Eventhough i am getting error message. any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the omniture documentation is referring to more recent versions of Cordova. The config.xml properties changed quite a bit from v2.5 to 3.x+

Comment: @gro Thanks for your comment. i will check with latest cordova version.